# how to number a resultset from MySQL (another option to not use user variables)

Tags: mysql, sql

For example a create this query to get all the users and their posts asociated

```
SELECT users.nameUser, posts.namePost
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id;
```

It works fine, but I need to number the results; so I declared a user variable in this way

```
SET @counter = 0;
```

Now I use it

```
SELECT (@counter := @counter + 1) AS NP, users.nameUser, posts.namePost
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id;
```

But now with MySQL 8 and window functions I need to use another way and avoid user variables

How I can achieve this?

Remember...

> If you need your variable increments its value you must to use the
>   `:=` sintax otherwise it keeps the same value no matter the size of
>   the resultset

Answer (score 1):

**Since MySQL 8 supports Window Functions, you can use: `row_number()`**

*Whats does row_number() do?*

> 1. It starts a counting since 1 and increments it on one plus one
> 2. row_number() needs to work with OVER clausule to make an asc o desc order over an specific column **(in this case nameUser)**

*My code should looks like this*

```
SELECT row_number() OVER(ORDER BY users.nameUser) AS NP, users.nameUser, posts.namePost
FROM users
JOIN posts ON users.id = posts.user_id;
```

Comment: @Ruzihm See [Can I answer my own question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Oh, neat. I didn't know that was a thing. Thanks!